# Database design in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an Access Database with 3 tables:

**Account Managers**

```
ID | Name | Office | Email | EmployeeID
```

**Clients**

```
ID | Name | EmployeeID
```

where `EmployeeID` indicates the responsible Account Manager. So far so good.

Now I also have Table3 (Task) where jobs regarding the clients gets registred.

**Tasks**

```
ID | Client Name | Task | Date | EmployeeID
```

My problem is, that when the `Clients` table gets updated (client gets a new Account Manager), that the `EmployeeID` on all tasks relating to this client i Table3 gets updated to the new EmployeeID.

Is it possible to "link" between the tables? Or would you suggest any other method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not have Client Name and EmployeeID in Table3, but use ClientID instead.

Comment: If the tasks are client specific NOT account manager specific then you should design the database to reflect this instead.

Comment: @Eydun Thank you. You mean the table should look like ID | ClientID | Task | Date and than build a join query where I query all client ID´s from the client table associated with the Account Manager and select all tasks with these ClientID from Table3 to show all tasks regarding this AM?!

Comment: @Dpolehonski The tasks are more account manager specific as I want to build reports showing all tasks registered for every AM.

Comment: In that case I would create a column which would store the ID of the account manager who performed the task, like a signature.

Comment: @user1204121 Yes, that is correct. You can always select the tasks for a employee by joining the tables.

Comment: @user1204121 What is the difference between ID and EmployeeID in the Account Managers table?

Comment: But how to update this signature when the client gets assigned a new Account Manager? I want to store the ID of the responsible AM, not of the one who created the task in the past.

Comment: @Eydun The difference is, that ID is an autoincremental field starting with "1" and increasing by "1" for every entry. The EmployeeID is the unique identificator in the firm.